# Render other controller method in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

As far as I know, a view is bound to a controller's action method like `PatientController` 's `Details` action method results are implemented in `Patient->Details.cshtml` inside the `Views` folder.

My question is how to call another controller action method like calling `Appointment`'s `Index` (in which I implemented a simple search `Index(string ID))` inside `Patient`'s `Details` and how to render or display the results.

I tried this inside `Details` (Patient)

```
<form asp-controller="Appointments" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id="ID" method="get">
    <p>
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ID)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => m.ID)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </p>
</form>
```

But that is rendering `Patient` ID property.

Comment: Here is an [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0) of tag helpers in .net core.The tag helpers in your form will help you go to the controller action.What does `rendering ControllerA ID property` mean?You want to pass somedata with `asp-route-id="ID"` to `ControllerB/Index`?

Comment: A controllers action binds a view, not the other way around. An action *should* correspond to an endpoint (eg a url pattern). You could write one action that calls others, then renders a view with data from both models...

Comment: @YiyiYou Yes, for instance ControllerA represents a page where a patient data are displayed (ID, name,...), I need to call also the page where his appointments to a clinic are stored (ControllerB) that's why I send the id to index to get the results.

Comment: You can use ControllerB:`public IActionResult Index(string id){return View();}`,and then you can get id in ControllerB/Index action,and go to ControllerB/Index.cshtml.

Comment: How to call call it? creating a new instance isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo:

ModelA:

```
public class ModelA
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

AController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new ModelA { ID="sampleID"});
        }
```

BController:

```
public IActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

A/Index.cshtml:

```
<h1>ControllerA/Index</h1>
<form asp-controller="B" asp-action="Index" asp-route-id=@Model.ID method="get">
    <p>
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.ID)
            </dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

B/Index.cshtml:

```
<h1>ControllerB/Index</h1>
```

result:
[image]